# How to remove certain html tags and leave content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the ul and li tags from this HTML-string but keep the content of them. So only remove the tags themselfs.

```
    <div>
<ul id="preview">
<li class="">
<div class="form-group">
        <div id="action-delete" class="ss-icon ss-trash pull-right" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"></div>
        <div id="action-edit" class="ss-icon ss-write pull-right" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"></div>
        <h4>Heading</h4>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

**Update**

This HTML is returned to me in a variable. How can I target only this HTML string and not the whole page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `unwrap()` twice :

```
$('#preview .form-group').unwrap().unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dy7e962y/)**

Comment: Close! But how can I only target the content of a specific string and not the whole page?

Comment: by creating selector that will target only the above div. in current case use id `preview` and  find `form-group` element in it.

Comment: I unfortunately need to only target the content of that string.

Comment: You can create hidden element on page with the returned html as its content. and then use above method to remove ul and li.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can `unwrap();` `ul li` form your `div class="form-group"`